# Nodejs typescript: export default for type does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

For variables I use this code:

> file.ts

```
const x = { ... }
const y = { ... }

export default { x, y }
```

> Use it:

```
import file from './file'

console.log(x.file)
```

But for types I can not use default export:

```
type x = { ... }
type y = { ... }

export default { x, y }
```

And I get this error:

```
'x' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

Comment: You're trying to default-export an _object_. You can't create that object because types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there any way to use types like object? `x.mytype`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Maybe you want a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe namespace works fine. thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to import `/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />` to files. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

> For variables I use this code:
>
> ```
> export default { x, y }
> ```

Well don't. That does not export variables, instead it's an object-literal in a default export. You don't want to create this object.

Instead, use named exports:

```
// file.ts
const x = { ... };
const y = { ... };

export { x, y }
```

or simply

```
// file.ts
export const x = { ... };
export const y = { ... };
```

Then use them as

```
import { x } from './file'

console.log(x);
```

or with namespace imports

```
import * as file from './file'

console.log(file.x);
```

This pattern will also work with types.